# PGFPLOTS: Drawings inside a bar of a barplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I have the following problem with a `xbar stacked` plot. The plot consist of three datasets and I want to draw two arrows at the beginning and the end of the second data set to highlight that the printed value in this bar belongs only to the second dataset and not to the overall data.

I created the following plot:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{grffile}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
                [xbar stacked,
                width=8cm,
                height=2cm,
                symbolic y coords={naive},
                ytick=data,
                yticklabels={Naive},
                xlabel={Runtime $[s]$},
                legend columns=3,
                legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south, legend cell align=left,
                align=left, legend plot pos=left, draw=black,font=\footnotesize},
                ]
                \draw[black, thick,<->] (axis cs: 100,naive) -- (axis cs: 1000,naive);
                \addplot+[green] coordinates {(100,naive)};
                \addlegendentry{Pre computations}
                %
                \addplot+[yellow,nodes near coords, node near coords style={black,font=\small\bfseries}]
                        coordinates {(900,naive)};
                \addlegendentry{Iteration}
                \addplot+[red] coordinates {(150,naive)};
                \addlegendentry{Post computations}
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in the following plot:
[image: mweplot]

By inserting

```
\draw[black, thick,<-] (axis cs: 100,naive) -- (axis cs: 250,naive);
\draw[black, thick,->] (axis cs: 850,naive) -- (axis cs: 1000,naive);
```

before the first `\addplot` command I achieve the desired output:
[image: wanted]

But I have the following problems with my solution:

Thereby, I had the following problems:

- The `draw` command needs to be before all `addplot` commands, otherwise
  it is in background.
- **But the more annoying problem:** At the moment I had to compute the start and the end of the bar piece from the data on my own. Is there a node/coordinate at the beginning or the end of each bar piece? In the example: Is there an automatically generated node at the beginning and the end of the yellow part of the bar or can such node be set automatically? Since in the end, I have around 20 rows and I do not want to compute the postion of both arrows by hand.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your desired output is. Would `\draw[black, thick,<-] (axis cs: 100,naive) -- (axis cs: 200,naive);` do what you want (and another one for the other side)? If not, then how should it look? The first problem (putting the draw command first) does not really seem like a problem, why would it be bad to put it first?

Comment: Techincally, I want `\draw[black, thick,<-] (axis cs: 100,naive) -- (axis cs: 200,naive);` and `\draw[black, thick,->] (axis cs: 900,naive) -- (axis cs: 1000,naive);` that would solve the second problem. But still I have to compute all coordinates beforehand. And relative coordindates seem not to work with symbolic names inside.

Comment: I am also a bit lost when reading the question. Any chance you can explain more clearly what you want to achieve?

Comment: I like to define` \coordinate`s inside the axis environment and draw outside the axis environment.

Comment: I reformulated the problem I bit and added the desired output generated with my unsatisfying solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are searching for the following result, right?

If yes, please read the comments up to `\begin{axis}` forward and then, inside the `axis` environment backwards.

You need to add the `\draw` command **before** the `\addplot` commands, because the `bar stacked` plots are drawn in **revered** order. So given your example, first it is drawn the red bar (from 0 to 1150) then the yellow and then the green. And by doing that the yellow bar stays on top of the red and the green on the yellow. And of course by stating other stuff before the first `\addplot` ensures then that this stuff also is on top of that bar.

```latex
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.16,
        % define a style to use for the connecting lines
        /tikz/my line style/.style={
            black,
            thick,
            ->,
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar stacked,
        width=8cm,
        height=2cm,
        symbolic y coords={naive},
        ytick=data,
        yticklabels={Naive},
        xlabel={Runtime [s]},
        legend columns=3,
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,1.05)},
            anchor=south,
            legend cell align=left,
            align=left,
            legend plot pos=left,
            draw=black,
            font=\footnotesize,
        },
        % !!! this is the critical point !!!
        % to make that solution work you have set the following option due to
        % technical reasons which is roughly:
        % normally the markers are first collected and are drawn *after*
        % `\end{axis}', in contrast to the `\draw' command. Said that, the
        % named `nodes near coords' are not available during the execution of
        % the `\draw' command
        clip marker paths=true,
    ]
        % draw the connecting lines using the predefined style
        \draw [my line style] (b-1-0) edge (a-0-1)
                                      edge (a-1-1)
        ;

        \addplot+[green] coordinates {(100,naive)}
            coordinate (a-\plotnum-\coordindex)
        ;
            \addlegendentry{Pre computations}

        \addplot+[
            yellow,
            nodes near coords,
            node near coords style={
                black,
                font=\small\bfseries,
                % also add names to the `nodes near coords`
                name=b-\plotnum-\coordindex,
            },
        ] coordinates {(900,naive)}
            % add coordinates to the points/bars
            coordinate (a-\plotnum-\coordindex)
        ;
            \addlegendentry{Iteration}

        \addplot+[red] coordinates {(150,naive)};
            \addlegendentry{Post computations}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am searching for. And thank you for the explaination why draw does not work.

Comment: One small problem is left. I have serveral dataset and add them via ` \addplot+[mygreen]   coordinates { (100,naive) (120,opt1) (125, opt2) }  } coordinate (a-\plotnum-\coordindex) ; ` and know the `a-x-y` coordinate is not longer found.

Comment: I thought so. But I didn't want to guess what else you do. I also think, that the answer will be too long for a comment, thus, I would like to ask you a [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536279/pgfplots-add-tikz-coordinate-to-each-coordinate-of-a-addplot-command