# Pgfplots - how to make additional inputs override main graph within axis?

Tags: pgfplots

I get this output:

[image]

You'll notice that the red rectangle is 'behind' the axis, whereas I want it to be 'on top of' the axis (so it covers the label).

The offending line in the code (MWE below) is:
`\node[red] at (axis cs: 1.5, -6){0.5};`

How can I bring it to the front? Note: I know that you can take it outside the axis environment, but then that prevents me from using `axis cs`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
currency, dep
IDR, 14.4
THB, 5.8
TWD, 2.9
SGD, 2.3 
KRW, 2.1 
PHP, 2.0
MYR, 0.5
CNY, 0.3 
}\charttwentyone

\begin{axis}[
font = \footnotesize,
width = 7cm, height = 7cm,
xbar, bar width=2mm,
axis lines=left,
enlarge y limits=0.1,
%
% x ticks style
xmin = 0.01, xmax = 15.8,
xtick distance = 2,
%
% y axis ticks and style
ytick=data, table/y expr = -\coordindex,     
yticklabels from table={\charttwentyone}{currency}, 
axis y line shift={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}},       
yticklabel shift={-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/axis y line shift}}, 
]
%
% done with the axis, now the plots
\addplot [fill, nodes near coords, draw opacity = 0]
table [x=dep]  {\charttwentyone};
\draw[fill,red] (axis cs: 0.9,-6.5) rectangle (axis cs: 2,-5.5);
\node[red] at (axis cs: 1.5, -6){0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that you "just" cover the number with the box. In the resulting PDF it is not a problem to select the text that is covered. Should that be avoided as well?

Comment: If you are "just" interested to draw something *on top* of whatever is there (as  muzimuzhi Z suggests in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/556789/pgfplots-how-to-make-additional-inputs-override-main-graph-within-axis/556804?noredirect=1#comment1404978_556804)), have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/536268/95441.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more like a trick, not the direct solution. I add

```
coordinate style/.condition=
  {\coordindex==6}{fill=red, text opacity=0}
```

to options of `axis` environment. Here `\coordindex` stores the current index of the table row (starting with 0), see [`pgfplots` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf), sec. 4.3.4 *Mathematical Expressions And File Data*.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
    currency, dep
    IDR, 14.4
    THB, 5.8
    TWD, 2.9
    SGD, 2.3 
    KRW, 2.1 
    PHP, 2.0
    MYR, 0.5
    CNY, 0.3 
  }\charttwentyone
  
  \begin{axis}[
    font = \footnotesize,
    width = 7cm, height = 7cm,
    xbar, bar width=2mm,
    axis lines=left,
    enlarge y limits=0.1,
    %
    % x ticks style
    xmin = 0.01, xmax = 15.8,
    xtick distance = 2,
    %
    % y axis ticks and style
    ytick=data, 
    table/y expr = -\coordindex,     
    yticklabels from table={\charttwentyone}{currency}, 
    axis y line shift={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}},       
    yticklabel shift={-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/axis y line shift}},
    coordinate style/.condition=
      {\coordindex==6}{fill=red, text opacity=0},
  ]
  
    % done with the axis, now the plots
    \addplot [fill, nodes near coords] table [x=dep]  {\charttwentyone};    
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I would say this is the first use of the new syntax that was added to v1.17. I consider your answer being perfect (and not as you state being a trick or an indirect solution).

Comment: @StefanPinnow I think a direct solution following OP's example is to draw something at the top level. That is most flexible. For covering specific nodes near coords, yes my answer is direct.